# Match values of columns from different sheets to return "yes" or "no"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to translate a formula to a VBA code.

Formula in row AA1:

```
=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(M1,'Sheet2'!J:J,0),"YES"),"NO")
```

If the value in Sheet 1 column M matches a value in Sheet 2 column J, the value in Sheet 1 column AA would be a "YES" else "NO".

The rows per column can change every day. Today the last row is AA500 and tomorrow could be AA55, the code should be flexible to loop up to the last row.

I tried the code I used for vlookup (which was working).

```vb
Dim r As Long
r = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Range("AA1").Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(R[1]C[-13],'Sheet2'!C[-10],0),""YES""),""NO"")"
Range("AA1").AutoFill Destination:=Range("AA1:AA" & r)
```

Answer (score 0):

You're writing an R1C1 style formula, so you need to use `.FormulaR1C1` and I've adjusted your column offsets to hit the columns you're after..

Try:

```
Range("AA1").FormulaR1C1 = "=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(RC[-14],'Sheet2'!C[-17],0),""YES""),""NO"")"
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work for you:

```
Sub tgr()
    
    'Define your workbook and worksheet objects
    Dim wb As Workbook:     Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet:   Set ws1 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet:   Set ws2 = wb.Worksheets("Sheet2")
    Dim rColM As Range:     Set rColM = ws1.Range("M1", ws1.Cells(ws1.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp))   'Define column M dynamically
    Dim rColJ As Range:     Set rColJ = ws2.Columns("J")
    
    'Populate column AA with the formula
    With Intersect(rColM.EntireRow, ws1.Columns("AA"))
        .Formula = "=IFERROR(IF(MATCH(M" & .Row & "," & rColJ.Address(external:=True) & ",0),""YES""),""NO"")"
    End With
    
End Sub
```